# Back-Merging Master into Develop includes a reverted commit

Tags: git

I'm in a bit of a git mess and need some help getting out of it. I'm attempting to back-merge master into develop after a release and it's included a commit that I believed was reverted. Here's how I got here:

1) Develop got accidentally merged into master.

2) Reverted the commit (922c6e7) from master that included develop

3) Re-committed the changes from 922c6e7 that were supposed to be there (basically someone branched off of develop and not master, and then merged into master)

4) I created a branch off of master that included 922c6e7, reverted that commit, and merged that into develop. My hope was that when I went to back-merge master into develop after the release, the revert commit would be taken care of.

5) Now I'm attempting to back-merge master into develop and it includes the commit 922c6e7.

How do I remove this revert from the PR?

Comment: Have you tried reverting the revert?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you want where... can you post the commit hashes for each, as they are now for develop & master.. and mark what you would like them to have been instead (or how you'd like them to be based on where they are now?).... e.g. in "5) Now I'm attempting to back-merge master into develop and it includes the commit 922c6e7"...  Presuming by the statement that "it" is not supposed to include the commit 922c6e7... but the "it" is referring to which, master or develop?  922c6e7 should be in develop, right? (just not in master). So not sure what exactly the issue is :s

Comment: m0bl, basically master has a commit (922c6e7) that is a revert. When I'm back merging master to develop, that revert (922c6e7) is included and is trying to revert code from develop that should be there.

I need to back-merge develop without that commit

Comment: Just read your Edit m0bl, no 922c6e7 is a revert of develop from master, so when that commit gets merged into develop it's reverting code that should be there.

Comment: @TimMcGee You may already know this - if `commit A` adds a file, and gets reverted, git does not delete `commit A` altogether - it creates `commit B` which removes that file. `commit B` is a revert commit.  If `commit B` is reverted, git creates `commit C` which re-adds the file. `commit C` is also a revert commit.  So it's normal to see `commit 922c6e7` lingering around even if it was reverted sucessfully.